# Count records grouped by weeks of the year

Tags: php, mysql

My table is basically an access log that records every page hit. What I want to display is the page hits per week for each of the weeks of the year, comparing year to year (so I have week 1 of 2013, 2014, 2015, week 2 of 2013, 2014 and so forth). I am currently accomplishing this by just querying all the records, and letting PHP do the heavy lifting as follows:

```
$result=$db->query("select `time` from accessTracking where `uID` is not null and `time`>1357030861 order by `time`");
foreach($result as $r){
    $y=date("Y",$r['time']);
    $w=ltrim(date("W",$r['time']),'0');
    $accessArray[$w][$y]++;
}
```

While it works, it takes a solid 7 seconds to load the page it displays the graph on, and I imagine there is not only a better way with PHP, but even more so with MySQL (which is what I'm looking for, but I'll take anything that gets the page load time down and makes the whole thing more efficient.

So, with that, the best I've come up with is:

```
select weekofyear(`time`) as week, count(*) as count from `accessTracking` where `uID` is not null group by week
```

This looks like it's going to work as it returns 53 rows with the "week" column from 1-52 and the "count" column with random values in them ranging from 2 to 1100. The problem is that the numbers should be way higher as the highest week I have is about 27,000 hits, and the first record returned in this query is a null "week" value with a "count" value of about 398,000. This is telling me that for most of the records, it's not calculating the weekofyear() value.

My guess is that I will in the end run this as separate queries for each year, as it may be too much to have it return the year, week number, and count, all grouped the way I want. But who knows!

Comment: It shouldn't be "too much" to add the extra grouping by year and I believe you're doing it the right way. I don't know enough about the `weekofyear()` function to speculate on that though.

Comment: Fred, the table is not indexed, but I'm not sure that it would be of much help here, we're not really searching or sorting the information that much. Every record has to be analyzed, and then sorted after that. Pagination really isn't an option as the final result set (for use on the page where the data is being displayed) is only the number of records for each week for each year, not the records themselves. Therefore, if you were wanting to display the results from the last three full years, you would only have 156 records to display. No big deal there.

Comment: I deleted my comment about that Patrick; I figured as much and was deleted before you posted your comment after. See the answers given below. However, indexing would help *a bit*. Gordon is far more advanced in SQL than I am.

Comment: I agree, it never hurts to index, I just didn't see a huge benefit in this particular case. Thanks for your input!

Comment: You're welcome, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are not comparable.  In particular, the first one has this condition:

```
`time` > 1357030861
```

This suggests that `time` is a unix time.  I would suggest that you try:

```
select weekofyear(from_unixtime(`time`)) as week, count(*) as count
from `accessTracking`
where `uID` is not null and `time` > 1357030861
group by week;
```

Comment: This was it. The query works and runs complete in less than half a second. It was simply not passing "weekofyear()" the right type of value it seems. Yes, `time` is a unix timestamp. It would seem I could even implement it returning the year as well without too much extra time. Thanks a lot Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not a good idea to use keywords or functions as your column names, as it leads to confusion and risk for bugs (and having to remember all the ` characters). I think this would do what you want, but with the year added to the results.

```
select weekofyear(from_unixtime(`time`)) as wk,
       year(from_unixtime(`time`)) as yr,
       count(*) as ct
from `accessTracking`
where `uID` is not null
group by wk, yr
```

For troubleshooting the strange results you're seeing, you should query for specific records and see how they match up to the aggregate. For example:

```
select `time` as access_time
from `accessTracking`
where `uID` is not null and
      weekofyear(from_unixtime(`time`)) = 1 and
      year(from_unixtime(`time`)) = 2015
```

Compare the row count from that query to what you get in the aggregate query. They should match, and if they don't you can better see where the discrepancy is. Naturally, I'd suggest choosing a week that has a smaller number of rows for troubleshooting, or rows that are showing results you feel are wrong.

Comment: I agree about the keywords issue. Not sure where my hashmarks got off to in that query, but I was having that trouble early on. Thanks for the reminder, and you were on the same track as Gordon with the from_unixtime() function. Perfect.